# Value of placement services for non-members

Tags: job-search

I am curious about what people think about value of limited period (typically, a year) placement services, provided by academic professional organizations, such as *Academy of Management*. For example, see [this page](http://aom.org/Placement/For-Job-Seekers.aspx). In particular, I am interested about the subject in the context of first-time academic job seekers, like me, targeting junior faculty or, more likely, postdoctoral opportunities. The reason I am asking this question is to determine the value and feasibility of those *time-limited placement services*, considering the availability of nice and free resources, such as [HigherEdJobs](https://www.higheredjobs.com).

Comment: It looks like the service provided by this organization is to post your anonymized resume on their web site for a fee, wait for employers to read the resume and contact the organization expressing interest, and then put them in touch with you.  I have some trouble believing that search committees are spending time trawling sites like this to try to recruit viable candidates.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you for the comment. I was also not sure about feasibility of using such services, considering the existence of unrestricted outlets, like HigherEdJobs - hence my question

Answer (score 6):

For industry jobs recruiters are very important for a first time employee seeking contract work.  However for academic jobs I doubt they're of any use.  Like you said there are academic job sites like Higher Ed.  Each discipline also usually has a career website.

If you're looking for postdoc positions your advisor is the best resource because many are given out by word of mouth alone.  Finally each institution is usually required to place job announcements and applications on their HR's web page.  So spend some time going to each University's website.

Comment: I strongly second this comment. Academic jobs are severe buyers' markets. Any attractive position is likely to have dozens, if not hundreds of well-qualified applicants banging down the doors. Committee members simply have no need to go casting around to get larger applicant pools.

Comment: Thank you, Mark and @shane (+1 to both), for your insights. I agree with you. I was skeptical about such service(s), but just wanted community's confirmation of my thoughts.